# Should I use TPL or Thread in a controller for scalability?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading

In my Controller I'm spawning 10 threads like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        new Thread(() => new ClassName()).Start();
        new Thread(() => new ClassName()).Start();
        new Thread(() => new ClassName()).Start();
        new Thread(() => new ClassName()).Start();
        new Thread(() => new ClassName()).Start();
    }
}
```

For exception handling purposes I'm thinking about using Task.Start (to use with Task.WaitAll());

Now I'm wondering:

As I understand, TPL uses threads from the precious thread-pool which can cause scalability issues and Thread does not.

What are the pro's and cons of using TPL vs Thread in a Controller in asp.net MVC 5?

Comment: The right answer depends on the workload that is to be run. Without this info, answers can only be speculative.

Comment: I feel that question is lack some of the information. Like what type of operation you want to perform and mainly it is cpu intensive or IO intensive.

Comment: Spawning 10 threads per Request certainly isn't scaleable. There are considerable time and space costs.

Comment: Like others have said, it's hard to say based on the contents of the question. If you're doing long-running, CPU bound operations, your controller is the wrong place for that. Consider off-loading the work to a service via a mechanism like WCF.

Comment: The processes are not CPU intensive.The threads are fetching information from other web services.

Comment: @Dimo in that case you should not be using ANY threads at all (TPL, Threadpool nor new Thread). You need to read http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html You should only use a Thread (in .net 4.5) when there is CPU involvement

Comment: @Dimo You should NEVER do any sort of threading with ASP.Net http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html

Comment: So how do I do asynchronous web service requests?

Comment: await client.GetAsync ...